# Python: Interpolate time not knowing exact pattern

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, interpolation, multi-index

I have dataframe (MultiIndex) which includes one datetime column with missing values (NaT). The time was collected in 0.2s interval but saved in seconds. Therefore, if not NaT, the dataframe would have 5 duplicates for each second, e.g.

```
2020-09-30 14:18:44 #for 14:18:44:00 
2020-09-30 14:18:44 #for 14:18:44:20
2020-09-30 14:18:44 #for 14:18:44:40
2020-09-30 14:18:44 #for 14:18:44:60
2020-09-30 14:18:44 #for 14:18:44:80
2020-09-30 14:18:45 #for 14:18:45:00
```

However, life ain't easy. So, my DataFrame looks like below and I would like to interpolate the time in the DT column. The only thing I know is that the measurements were continuous for each Group (*Gr* column) with 0.2s time interval. What I do not know is:

- at which decisecond the measurement has started for a group.
- which decisecond was saved (one value may represent 0.2 s whereas the next saved output may be 0.6)

Because of the first bullet, I cannot use modulo (i.e. `No` where `x%5 == 0` represents 0.0 s) because `x%5 == 0` may represent 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 or 0.8 s.
The second bullet prevents me from filling NaT values by time interval starting from the first time occurrence for a group. This is what I have tried (code example at the end) but it doesn't work for e.g. group B as the output would look like this:

```
B   18  4   NaT
    19  7   NaT
    20  11  NaT
    21  3   NaT
    22  7   NaT
    23  5   2020-09-30 14:30:43:00
    24  23  2020-09-30 14:30:43:02
    25  1   2020-09-30 14:30:43:04
    26  9   2020-09-30 14:30:43:06 #missing 0.8 sec. here
    27  2   2020-09-30 14:30:44:00
    28  4   2020-09-30 14:30:44:02
```

The sample data which I'm providing below are not large but I hope it's enough to present my problem. My original data have >100 rows for each Group (index level=0) so I am sure it is possible to figure out the pattern, I just don't know how to do it.

Sample data, where:
`Gr` - group MultiIndex level = 0;
`No` - ID of measurement, may start at e.g. 18 for a Group (it means that 0-17 were excluded from further processing), MultiIndex level = 1;
`x` - value of measurement;
`DT` - datetime of measurement.

```
        x   DT
Gr No       
  A 1   2   2020-09-30 14:18:43
    2   4   NaT
    3   5   NaT
    4   2   NaT
    5   4   NaT
    6   6   2020-09-30 14:18:44
    7   9   NaT
    8   9   NaT
    9   9   NaT
    10  9   NaT
    11  1   2020-09-30 14:18:45
    12  2   NaT
    13  6   NaT
    14  8   NaT
    15  22  NaT
  B 18  4   NaT
    19  7   NaT
    20  11  NaT
    21  3   NaT
    22  7   NaT
    23  5   2020-09-30 14:30:43
    24  23  NaT
    25  1   NaT
    26  9   NaT
    27  2   2020-09-30 14:30:44
    28  4   NaT
    29  3   NaT
    30  11  NaT
    31  15  NaT
    32  20  NaT
  C 0   13  NaT
    1   6   2020-09-30 14:48:53
    2   22  NaT
    3   26  NaT
    4   2   NaT
    5   7   NaT
    6   3   2020-09-30 14:48:54
    7   6   NaT
    8   1   NaT
    9   9   NaT
    10  2   NaT
    11  14  2020-09-30 14:48:55
    12  24  NaT
    13  20  NaT
    14  5   NaT
```

Sample data:

```
data = {
'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],  
'No': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],  
'x': [2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 2, 6, 8, 22, 4, 7, 11, 3, 7, 5, 23, 1, 9, 2, 4, 3, 11, 15, 20, 13, 6, 22, 26, 2, 7, 3, 6, 1, 9, 2, 14, 24, 20, 5, 3, 6, 9, 22, 15, 4, 21, 15, 12, 10, 12, 5, 8, 1, 7, 24, 2, 19, 6, 9, 23, 26, 21, 13, 3, 9, 12, 9, 13, 18, 14, 20, 9, 8, 20, 7, 3, 1, 7, 11, 6, 5, 2, 9, 3],  
'DT': ['2020-09-30 17:18:43', None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:18:44', None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:18:45', None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:18:46', None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:18:47', None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:18:48', None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:18:49', None, None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:30:43', None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:30:44', None, None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:30:45', None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:30:46', None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:30:47', None, None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:48:53', None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:48:54', None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:48:55', None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:48:56', None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:48:57', None, None, None, None, '2020-09-30 17:48:58', None, None, None]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df = df.set_index(keys = ["Group", "No"])
df["DT"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DT"])
```

And a piece of code which I have used to calculate the time interval assuming that first time occurrence is a measurement at 0.0 s. Which is wrong. bfill code in a similar manner.

```
mask = df["DT"].notna() #bool for NaT
g = df["DT"].groupby([pd.Grouper(level = 0), mask.cumsum()]) #group by Group, cumsum for NaT-bool
t = pd.to_timedelta(g.cumcount() * 0.20, unit = "s") #calculate time interval
df["DT"] = df['DT'].groupby(level = 0).ffill() + t #ffill
```